# how to compare month returned by date()

Tags: php, date

I've a code snippet:

```
<?php
    echo $tm = date("M", strtotime("31-Mar-2013"))."\n";
    echo $tm;
    if($tm == "Mar"){
        echo "March";
    }
?>
```

and I supposed the output will be:

```
Mar
Mar
March
```

But I'm getting only

```
Mar
Mar
```

Can anybody tell me why `March` is not being printed?
The [program](http://ideone.com/xVGSoc) is also [here](http://ideone.com/xVGSoc)

Comment: Working fine here http://codepad.org/N7xsISpB.

Comment: I tried the script and I get "MarMarMarch".

Comment: Even i tried the script i got MarMarMarch as output....

Comment: The output is shown as `MarMarMarch` in the ideone link too.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me out. I'd overlooked the `\n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't paste the code with which you have problem, what you posted above works. But looking at the source on the link you posted, your problem is concatenation with newline

`echo $tm = date("M", strtotime("31-Mar-2013"))."\n";`

If you remove `"\n"` it will work

Comment: thanks for bringing into my notice that `\n`. I just overlooked it.

Answer (score 2):

From your [ideone code](http://ideone.com/xVGSoc) remove `"\n"` in line `24`.